# Imagemagick stack images overlapping with transparency

Tags: transparency, layer, imagemagick-convert

I am fighting this for two days now... without success. Some task I have done with Gimp for some time but I like to make it automated now for standard processing.

So the result should look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDUc0.jpg
Kind of one image in front and the two or three behind it with some transparency to fade the layers out (optional).
There are always the same image dimension in one group. But the dimensions can differ to other groups. Example: one group to combine is each image 124x112px, another group is each 188x80px and the next is 164x160px.

I have tried something like

`convert image1.png image2.png image3.png -set page '+%[fx:u[t-1]page.x+u[t-1].w-256]+%[fx:u[t-1]page.y+16]' -background none -layers merge +repage output.png`

which was working fine (except the optional transparency) for some files.
I don't really require a procentual offset, it would be ok if each layer is offset by like 30x5px. But the output image should be relational to the input image.

So, in short.. really puzzled right now how to achieve this. Hope someone can help. 
I've also studied the PHP Imagick Extension https://www.php.net/manual/de/book.imagick.php
There I had the following approach which was even worse to the above

```
  $imagick->newimage(200, 112, '#ffffffff');
  foreach ($uploadfiles as $file) {    
    $im = new Imagick($file);
    $imagick->compositeimage($im, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 30, 5);
  }
  $imagick->writeImage($output);
```

It seems it didn't offset it at all.

Anyone has a helping hand for me?

Comment: Please post a set of your input images. What is your version of Imagemagick. Your command should have worked fine for images with transparency. What result did you get that was not correct?

Comment: here's a example of two sets https://filehorst.de/d/dtDcmkeB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me in Imagemagick 6.

Input:

[image]

```
convert lena.png \( lena.png -duplicate 2 -alpha set -channel a -evaluate set 75% \) lena.png -set page '+%[fx:u[t-1]page.x+u[t-1].w-128]+%[fx:u[t-1]page.y+16]' -background none -layers merge +repage output.png
```

[image]

The first and last images are opaque and the middle 3 are 75% opaque (25% transparent)

ADDITION:

If you only want a fixed X offset of 30 and no Y offset, then use

```
convert lena.png \( lena.png -duplicate 2 -alpha set -channel a -evaluate set 75% \) lena.png \
-set page '+%[fx:u[t-1]page.x+30]+0' -background none -layers merge +repage output.png
```

[image]

Comment: that seems to work pretty well, I wonder why it doesn't worked for me, the page parameter is the same? Now just how to do this with 2 up to 5 different images?

Comment: Just change the -duplicate for as many images above 2 as you want. I do not know why it does not work for you. What is your Imagemagick version and platform? Perhaps a buggy or not properly upgraded version?

Comment: tried it locally and on server. Local is Linux Mint, server is Ubuntu 18.04, both running IM 6.9.7

Comment: Did you use my exact command and image?  Did you have the images and command running from the same directory? What was the full version number (convert -version will tell you).

Comment: I've added earlier to set of example images to your answer in the original thread. The exact version is 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114  I've played around more with it and it works _mostly_ for my image sets but some gives really weird results even they are not really different. But like they are going from right to left. Pretty weird. I am thinking if it wouldn't be better to shift each layer by a fixed pixel width

Comment: What is a weird result?  Is it a weird color or not the offset you expect?  If a weird color, are your images all RGB or some RGB and some CMYK?

Comment: I think I figured it now. One last question if I may, how can I make the layer just shift by 30 pixel on x?

Comment: What change in y? As is, or no change?

Comment: just absolute 30 px on x, no change in y

Comment: I can't make sense out of the page parameter. All I get is image shifted by a few pixel but cut off at the border (image size is not extended at all). So pretty lost with that.

Comment: Post your code and your version of ImageMagick and platform.

Comment: Linux Mint 19.2, IM 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 and the current code I have is   convert " . $uploadnames . "-set page '+%[fx:u[t-1]page.x+u[t-1].w-128]+%[fx:u[t-1]page.y+16]' -background none -layers merge +repage '" . $output . "' That is not the 30px version. For this I tried to replace the page.x+u[t-1].w-128] with +30

Comment: Your IM 6.9.7.4 is from 2017. You should try to upgrade if you can. If you do that replace, you will not get the relative shifts. It will put all the images but the first 30 pixels from the left edge. You need that page computation as I wrote it. If you want to shcange the 30 to something else, that is fine. It should still work. I just tested my code above on IM 6.9.7.4 Q16 Mac OSX and it worked fine.

Comment: I would also like to understand the geometry parameter passed to `-set page`. Unfortunately, I have not yet found the right part of the documentation. The general geometry spec documentation as well as `-page` or `-set` do not seem to explain this, but I am sure it's written somewhere?! There's also only one hit when searching for "%[" in the documentation, and that's quite unhelpful as well.

Comment: See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/transform/#fx_escapes and https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php and https://imagemagick.org/script/fx.php and https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#virtual_canvas and https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#layers

Comment: Also https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#define